# Is every page a new view?

Tags: design-patterns, ios

I just started building an iOS app and wanted to get some feedback regarding views.

I've got specs for

```
Activity Page
Activity Recording
Activity Create
Activity Save
```

Each of the specs show a different function, but would each of these be a brand new view in my iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, each different "page" of your application is a different view. Each view will probably want its own view controller (subclass of `UIViewController`), too.

Comment: So would it be best to then subclass these under a view controller that I've already created named ActivityViewController ?

Comment: That depends. Normally you wouldn't need to create a multi-level inheritance hierarchy below `UIViewController`, you can simply create each one as a separate direct descendant of `UIViewController`. It would be hard for us to answer without knowing a lot more about your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have it as separate screens. You can use different view controllers for different screens. But if any of the features such are too small or you dont have much to fill the screen, you can add it on the main screen(for eg:- reordering of activities).

In order to connect these screens, you can use UITabbarController if the screens are completely independent of each other. In case they are dependent, use UINavigationController and/or modal view controllers.